# Enforce GitHub status checks for only pull requests

Tags: github, travis-ci

I keep seeing two Travis status checks showing up in my PRs. I only want the PR status checks to show up, not the branch pushes:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the repository settings on travis you can disable building (any) pushes altogether. You can not control/limit which status to report.